# Windows Server 8 does not recognize my graphic card driver

Tags: graphics-card, windows-8-preview, windows-server, display-driver

I have an HD4650. First I installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview and the card worked well even without installing a Catalyst driver. And now I switch to Windows Server 8 beta where it stumbles. Even after I install [Catalyst 12.1 of Windows 7 64-bit](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_vista64.aspx) and later the [Catalyst Windows 8 Consumer Preview Driver](http://downloads.guru3d.com/AMD-Catalyst-Windows-8-Consumer-Preview-Driver-download-2866.html), it is still recognized as "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" and using BasicDisplay.sys as its driver. How can I get it work normally in Windows Server 8? Thank you~

**UPDATE**:
There is no driver listed in the Catalyst Install Manager. Only the CCC is displayed.

Comment: As this is a consumer preview ther are likley many drivers that do not work or are unavailable

Comment: I wonder whether others are facing the same problem.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a Windows 7 driver?  The only drivers you should be using is the Catalyst Windows 8 Consumer Preview Driver.  While Windows 7 and Windows 8 are similar they do not share the same drivers at this time.

Comment: From the .inf file I cannot see the HD4600 series.

Comment: @Ramhound: Incorrect, the majority of drivers works with a compatibility installation.

Comment: @DaveM: Incorrect, the driver architecture has not changed much.

Comment: Ideally you want WDDM 1.2 drivers vrs WDDM 1.1 drivers, but win8 can handle both. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model#WDDM_1.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 8 Server optimized to be a server not for use as a workstation, so it always prefers Basic Display Adapter (Microsoft code) over a device specific one (third party code).

You can override that behavior by

1. Open up "Device Manager"
2. Find your Display Adapter in the tree of devices
3. Right click on it and select "Update Driver Software"
4. Select "Browse for driver software on your computer"
5. Select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
6. If the WDDM compatible driver is there, select it, otherwise use "Have Disk".

You can also use this methodto force Microsoft Basic Display Adapter on a workstation.

Comment: Thank you and it works! I also found a page about modifying .msi files: http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=352390 . Note that the OS strings for Windows 8 are WIN_WIN8_64 and WIN_WIN8_SVR

Comment: I have to supplement that I am using a Win7 driver now.